# Tkinter error. Unknown option -command for button.(Python 3)

Tags: python, tkinter

I  need help in this small code I just made:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root, width=20)
e.grid(row=0, column=0)

def btn_clicked():
    label = Label(root, text=f"Hello {e.get()}!")
    label.grid(row=1, column=0)

button = Button(root, padx=10, text="Click this", COMMAND=btn_clicked)
button.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `COMMAND=...` should be `command=...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `COMMAND=btn_clicked` to `command=btn_clicked`